# 36 * 8 = 44, 27 * 12 = 23

Tags: mathematics

Was playing a game today and encountered [this puzzle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiPbh.png). What's the rule behind it?

> 36 * 8 = 44, 27 * 12 = 23
> 19 * 4 = 43. Therefore, what is 50 * 8?

The answer is

> 62

Source: Black desert online, the herald journal part 4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The star stands for

> divide, then concatenate the remainder to it.

Therefore

> $50 * 8 = 6\ R\ 2$, so $62$

Comment: Great! I too came across the same problem